# Return multiple output variables from postgres function

Tags: postgresql, return, plpgsql

When I run the function below, I get nulls in the two output values `p_V_RESULT` and `p_V_ERROR_MSG`. What could be the problem?

The `RAISE INFO` shows values assigned:

```
INFO:  p_V_RESULT,T,p_V_ERROR_MSG
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE   FUNCTION public.CheckSessionFailed (
IN p_V_CHK_SESSION_ID   bigint,
IN p_V_ERROR_COMMENT    varchar(1000) ,
OUT p_V_RESULT          char(1)         ,
OUT p_V_ERROR_MSG       varchar(1000)  
) 
AS $$
DECLARE
    p_V_RESULT  char(1) := 'T';
    p_V_ERROR_MSG varchar(1000)  := NULL;
    errMsg text;
    errState text;
    errContext text;
    r_rec record;
BEGIN
    p_V_RESULT   := 'T';
    p_V_ERROR_MSG  := '';

    UPDATE CHECK_SESSION
    SET SEVERITY_CD = 'FATAL',
        SESSION_COMMENT = 'Check Session Failed: ' || COALESCE(p_V_ERROR_COMMENT, ''),
        SESSION_END_DATE = NOW(),
        UPDATED_STATUS_FLG = 'Y',
        LAST_UPDATED = NOW()
    WHERE CHK_SESSION_ID = p_V_CHK_SESSION_ID;

    RAISE INFO 'p_V_RESULT,%,p_V_ERROR_MSG,%',p_V_RESULT,p_V_ERROR_MSG;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS
            errState = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
            errMsg   = MESSAGE_TEXT,
            errContext = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
        p_V_ERROR_MSG := 'SQL State: '|| errState || ';Message ' || errMsg || '; Context '|| errContext;
        p_V_RESULT := 'F';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: select * from CheckSessionFailed ( 1::bigint, 'pano'::varchar(1000));

Comment: When i removed the p_V_RESULT and p_V_ERROR_MSG from DECLARE section it worked

Comment: Ah, yes. I didn't see the double definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `OUT` parameter in a function automatically defines a variable with the name of the parameter.

Your explicit declaration

```
DECLARE
    p_V_RESULT  char(1) := 'T';
    p_V_ERROR_MSG varchar(1000)  := NULL;
```

overrides and shadows those parameters. So you end up assigning to the wrong variables.

The solution is to remove these second variable declarations.